# How to prove you live somewhere when you live at some friend house for the National Insurance Number in UK?

Tags: united-kingdom

Got a problem : I will apply for the National Insurance Number in UK, I need to prove I live somewhere they ask me for an invoice with my name ... : / 
Yet I live at my friend's house ... How can I prove it then ? Should I sleep in an hostel for a day ?

Here is the official link about applying for a National Insurance Number :

https://www.gov.uk/apply-national-insurance-number

Comment: @solarflare I just want to work legally ! That's why I need this Insurance Number. They ask me for an invoice with my name. I live with these friends and I don't know whether we I have to have an invoice with my name from a random hostel or if a paper from my friends saying I live with them is sufficient

Comment: @ThePassenger gnashers answer below is good, dont go trying to be deceptive, use the address you're living in.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about providing evidence of residence and not about navigating the workplace.

Comment: As an expat who formerly lived in the UK, this can be a genuine challange @solarflare; it's a bit of a catch-22 since you need a "proof of address" for many services that many provide you with such proof. I had similar problems moving to New Zealand a few weeks ago (I am renting, and the contract was my "proof", but if I had been staying at my girlfriend's it would have been tricky). Also see: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/85/7023

Comment: I also think this is on-topic, as it involved the National Insurance Number, which is required to work in the UK. There are many questions about it already: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/search?q=national+insurance

Comment: @HorusKol No, all these information about where I live are for the UK Department for work and pension in order to have the National Insurance Number to be allowed to work legally as far as I don't have a proper home and live by the charity of my friends.

Comment: If you live with a friend sign a lodger agreement with them or the landlord. Make sure your friend is authorized to take you in as a lodger. That should do it.

Comment: @ThePassenger I think the right site to ask this question is at [expats.se], for people living abroad on a long-term basis.

Comment: I'm not sure how different the UK and France are on that point, but in France, if you were in this situation you'd need 3 things : (1) a proof of residence for **your friend** (2) a copy of their ID (3) a letter written and signed by your friend where they explicitly state they are hosting you for free

Comment: Have you asked the DHSS, your embassy or the  Citizens Advice Bureau  for help

Comment: @rath I asked my friend about the lodget agreement but she answered me _a lodger agreement would mean my mum's household income would be higher so it would be bad for her_. I just [asked the question on Expatriates as well](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/15033/how-to-prove-you-live-somewhere-when-you-live-at-some-friend-house-for-the-natio) following David K advice.

Comment: You should add that to your Expats question since it's extremely relevant. Also include if you pay rent or if you are a guest.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get an NI number, and fortunately that's not handled by the Home Office.

Assuming that you are not living with your friend for free, ask your friend to give you an invoice for the rent you are paying him. With your name on it. Alternatively, you ask the people who told you to provide a bill with your name what they would want, since you are not getting bills for rent, electricity, water etc.

Comment: Unfortunately I do live with them for free :) The people who asked me to provide the bill, the work and pension department of UK, would like any invoice with my name on it.

Comment: you could try getting a mobile phone contract with paper billing for that address

Comment: @mgh42 Thanks for your comment. Any address ?

Comment: @ThePassenger the address of your friends house where you are living

Comment: But to open a bank account you need a proof of address @HorusKol >_<

Comment: Isn't the council tax related to the number of people living in the house?

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti no, the council tax is based on value of property not how many people live there.  You do get a discount if you're a student or living alone, but that's the extent of any discount.  It's not based on number of people living there.